# Is it possible for me to play as a half-dragon and if so what would my stats be?

Tags: dnd-5e, dragons, human

I love dragons but I don't want to be a full dragon or a full human all the time so I want to play as a 1/2 dragon, 1/2 human but to clarify what I mean by 1/2 Dragon is human form but just add Dragon tail, claws, horns, and eyes, and maybe wings. Also my character has the ability to either be full human or full dragon but can't sustain it for prolonged periods of time without passing out from the mentula strain.

PS the PC I'm making is not an adult but a teenager in the 13-16 range.

Comment: Have you asked your DM? Are you looking for advice on if this is possible rules-as-written or for a way to homebrew this in a balanced way? What is the context of your campaign, i.e. is this supposed to be a character that can do this from level one or a goal your character will work towards achieving as the campaign goes on?

Comment: can do at level one but can hold forms for prolonged periods of time without passing out from the mental strain

Comment: Do you intend to only flavor your character as being dragon-like in appearance or do you wish for your character to have stats and features (like flight) equivalent to any other dragon you might fight during your adventure? I cannot imagine any GM allowing the latter at level one.

Comment: i kind of wanted to have wings, tail, horns, eyes, and the claws in the 1/2 form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148494/discussion-between-goodguy5-and-drake-the-dragon).

Comment: @Kryomaani are there shapeshifting charms

Comment: What is the composition of the rest of the party, as in what races?

Comment: @Senmurv i am just trying to create a character

Comment: @Drakethedragon okidoke - I wanted to write you a response in terms of balance in a party, which is why I'm curious about other players' choice of races.

Comment: @Senmurv this is just a  character I'm just creating so I can have it.

Comment: Is  there a reason that you are not creating a PC with the dragonborn race?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast yes there is a reason that I'm not creating a PC with the dragon race and the reason is that I didn't want to play a full dragon the hole game but I still wanted to play as a dragon so I thought of playing as a half dragon so I can still be a dragon but also play as a human as well.

Comment: I wrote "dragonborn" and that is what I mean. Dragonborn.  That is a PC race who is a humanoid, and is in the PHB.  Any warlock or sorcerer can use disguise self to appear as a human once they get to that level.  You can't have it all at first level.  The game is designed to grow into your character through the play of the game.

Comment: @Drakethedragon you still have not answered my query about the other races playd in your party :)

Comment: @Mazura [Please don’t answer in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments).

Answer (score 16):

### There is a couple of options to be dragon-ish

A "half-dragon" in 5e might be:

#### 1. The Draconic Bloodline sorcerer's origin

> Most often, sorcerers with this origin trace their descent back to a mighty sorcerer of ancient times who made a bargain with a dragon or who might even have claimed **a dragon parent.**

#### 2. The Dragonborn race

> **Born of dragons**, as their name proclaims, the dragonborn walk proudly through a world that greets them with fearful incomprehension.

Neither is close to a true dragon in terms of power, however, both have a distinct draconic flair.

Also, [Dragonlance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonlance) setting has its **Draconians**. I don't know what setting do you play.

---

A worthy addition from the comments:

#### 3. Way of the Ascendant Dragon

A Monk archetype from Fizban's Treasury of Dragons:

> The fundamental teaching of this tradition holds that by emulating dragons, a monk becomes a more integrated part of the world and its magic. By altering their spirit to resonate with draconic might, monks who follow this tradition augment their prowess in battle, bolster their allies, and can even soar through the air on draconic wings.

You could even combine all three (thanks to @Kirt for the example):

> have a PC that is a dragonborn monk (way of the ascended dragon) / draconic bloodline sorcerer (currently level 1/2). The idea is that he is becoming more dragonlike as he increases in power

Regardless, there is no legit way to turn a low-level PC into a dragon. Adult dragons are very strong in D&D (5e in particular), so making dragon a PC almost certainly breaks the game until very high (17-18) levels. However, you can become more and more dragon-like.

Comment: As @goodguy5 pointed out in chat workshopping the question with the querant, there is also the Way of the Ascendand Dragon monk from Fizban's.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin, good finding! However, it's about "emulating dragons", not heritage.

Comment: BION, have a PC that is a dragonborn monk (way of the ascended dragon) / draconic bloodline sorcerer (currently level 1/2).  The idea is that he is becoming more dragonlike as he increases in power.

Comment: No, but you can turn a dragon into a low level PC who *just can't seem to get it back together* after Huma died.

Answer (score 8):

#### No official player options have this ability until 17th level.

There are no official player options that do this unless you are playing in a high level game. A 17th level spellcaster with access to *true polymorph* or *shapechange* can use one of these spells to change into an adult dragon.

Comment: well i was going to play a fighter but still if i could be a 1/2 dragon what would my stats be

Comment: and would a magic charm solve the spellcaster problem

Comment: @Drakethedragon there is no simple way for a fighter to become a dragon per the rules. The best you could do is try and work with your GM to come up with a homebrew way to achieve this, but you also need to recognize that giving your character powers that are even remotely close to a dragon as depicted in the game will massively overpower any party member characters built according to the rules until you're close to level 20. Have you considered playing a dragonborn?

Comment: well my first DM/GM did let me use the dragonborn race so that I could be a 1/2 dragon and 1/2  human

Comment: @Drakethedragon In 5e at least, Dragonborn are neither half-dragon nor half-human. They’re just Dragonborn. But that race may fit the idiom your looking for in a character.

Comment: well my DM/GM let me use it that way

Comment: @ThomasMarkov No reason they can't flavour it that way.

Comment: I know dragons are overpower so the one I'm playing as is a teenager in the 13-16 range

Comment: @Jason_c_o can a shapeshifting work if there are any

Comment: @Drakethedragon A brand new, baby, just hatched wyrmling is (at minimum, depending on type) more deadly on its own than a level 1 Adventurer. By the time they are 'adolescent,' they are (again, at minimum) more dangerous than a 6th level adventurer. Being a 'teenager dragon' with adventurer levels on top of draconic capabilities is still grossly overpowered :D

Answer (score 8):

Others have already addressed this, but **there is no way (within the rules) to make a level 1 character be able to transform into a dragon.**

The only way I can see you getting the power you want is through some sort of homebrew, one that you can search for or one you can create with your DM. A power of this magnitude is not something that an early game character should have. Here's an example of how I would handle a request like this.

### You're a dragon that's been cursed.

Somehow, for some reason, before the campaign begins, your character his gotten on some powerful spell-caster's bad side and you've gotten cursed, transformed into a young human and severely weakened. Now with the strength of a level 1 PC, you begin your search for someone that can undo this curse. This can be a major plot hook for your group's campaign, or a personal side quest that your party can assist you with.

As for stats, you've been weakened to a standard human, for now. As this specific plot line progresses during the campaign and you gain levels, I as a DM would unlock different draconic powers in addition to your chosen class features. Here are some examples of what I'd unlock early on:

- You get access to your wings and can fly for a short time
- You get access to your breath weapon and can use it on recharge 6 (weaker than recharge 5, but better than limited use from the Dragonborn race)
- You get access to your frightening presence and can attempt to frighten creatures of your choice in an area a limited number of times

This is just what I could think of off the top of my head, it would be up to you **and** your DM to come up with the abilities you want and how you would gain access to them. Getting the features of such a powerful creature is going to take some work to make sure you don't completely over shadow your teammates in your party.

Comment: are there shapeshifting charms

Comment: You *are* a dragon, you just suck at it. <pokes Lambert with a stick> common' do the thing.... <pokes Lambert's *mom* with a stick> Now you done eff up son....

Comment: @Drakethedragon None that I can find will turn you into a dragon. The closest thing I could find is a Wand of Polymorph, but this only lets you transform into beasts. And dragons are dragons, not beasts. Obviously the DM runs the world and can add whatever they want into the world. If this is something you seriously want, you'll have to work something out with them.

Answer (score 6):

First - I'd suggest talking with your DM about it. My experience suggests that attempting to bruteforce character, who is not to DM's liking into game by hitting DM with rules till they'd give into it - is a bad way to start a game.

Second - you can ask GM to 'reskin' one of existing races, saying that you'd take their statistics, but will look like a dragon. I'd suggest trying Aarakocra from Mordekainen Presents: Monsters of Multiverse - they have both wings and flying speed, plus unarmed attack with their talons, which makes them perfect candidates to be reskinned into humanoid dragon.

Third - there is an option 'custom lineage' from Tasha's Cauldron of Everything which gives you full control over your character's origin and looks - but in that case those would only cosmetic options - no real flight or anything.

Only one race (afaik) can shapeshift as a racial ability - those are Changelings, but in their case change is only cosmetic, they don't get any special abilities of those they change into.

Answer (score 0):

#### It is possible to be an half dragon, but it requires a considerable amount of work and cooperation with your DM.

*Advice: From what you wrote in this question, in the comments, in chat and in another question, it seems to me that you are a newbie in 5th edition of DnD: I kindly suggest to read the Player's handbook, in order to have a general sight about the rules. Moreover,  I suggest then to bring this character idea to your DM and work it with them, in order to achieve a playable and balanced character.*

Your DM may adapt the [Half Dragon template](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16918-half-red-dragon-veteran) in the Monster Manual: from the description of such creature we can read:

> When a dragon in polymorphed form mates with another creature, the union sometimes produces half-dragon offspring. A creature might also transform into a half-dragon as a result of a mad wizard’s spell or a ritual bath in dragon’s blood. In all these cases, the result is a creature that combines the essence of a dragon with the form of its original race. Regardless of their origins, all half-dragons have similar features and appearance, gaining special senses, resistance to destructive energy, and a breath weapon.

It gains more senses, resistance and the breath weapon related to the lineage of the dragon bloodline (chromatic or metallic). Using this template, the DM may add more details and/or features, as for example the usage of wings once a certain level is reached<sup>1</sup>, or looking more dragon-ish a limited number of times per day.

Nonetheless, the DM has to take into account that this template covers the creation of monsters/NPCs, that usually follow different rules with respect to player characters's one.

#### Becoming a dragon X times per day will be *quite* unbalanced.

I would pay particular care in allowing becoming a true dragon: in the first tiers of play this could be really unbalanced, dragons are powerful creatures<sup>2</sup>, as Illustro notes in their [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/208185/63061).

There are some spells ([*True Polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph), [*Draconic Transformation*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/draconic-transformation)) that allow to become a full dragon, or even magic items (*e.g.* Potion of Dragon's Majesty, as stated in this [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/208200/63061) to the other question of yours), but they are powerful and available at high levels, they are not suitable to low level characters, particularly for 1st level ones.

---

<sup>1</sup> Check for comparison [Drows](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/3-elf#DarkElfDrow) or [Tieflings](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/7-tiefling#TieflingTraits), that gain the usage of a 2nd level spell once the 5th level is reached, regardless the class.

<sup>2</sup> Well, we are playing Dungeons and *Dragons*...

Comment: Thank you for your help and the 1/2 dragon templet that should help me create the character. Also the 1/2 dragon I'm playing as is in the 13-16 years old range does that change anything with the dragons powerfulness.

Comment: @Drakethedragon I think it might be good for you to go to the PHB and read a bit more about character progression (classes). There is no such thing as a 13-16 year-old half-dragon character, so you'd need to agree the details with your DM. The character progression mostly is related to the class you choose - not the race or age - some races do have some advancement as they progress in levels (but not age), e.g. get additional innate spell-casting abilities. But, that you'd need to work out with your DM.

Comment: @Drakethedragon I strongly suggest to have a look at the Player's handbook, to have a little bit more precise idea about the rules, classes, races and so on, for creating a playable character that reflects the background story that you have in mind.

Comment: @Drakethedragon If I may provide another advice, for the first times it is better to play one of the race and one of the classes in the player's handbook before going in the homebrew world.

Answer (score -1):

### Character creation

If I wanted to focus on what you call the 'strain' of your character hiding/showing their features right from level 1, I would start with the Custom Lineage and take the Eldritch Adept feat for the Mask of Many Faces invocation and use the *disguise self* spell to constantly be shifting in appearance between my more human or draconic sides. Custom Lineage also lets "You determine your appearance" with your initial cosmetic features, so you can tailor your underlying 'default' half-dragon look.

If I wanted to focus more on practical dragon features like breath weapon or flight at character creation, I would start with the (Gem) Dragonborn (breath weapon, and flight from level 5) or Winged Tiefling (fire resistance and flight from 1st level).

### Playing the character

For the feeling of occasionally losing control and becoming a massive dragon-like beast, I actually think playing a Moon Druid would be fun. Work with your DM to add dragon flavour to the wild shapes, like Deinonychus dinosaur at level 2 and the huge flying Quetzalcoatlus dinosaur by level 8. Cantrips like Primal Savagery (claws and teeth), Thunderclap (roar), and Create Bonfire (fire) all fit the build when not wildshaped. Normal stats for a druid would be Wisdom highest, Constitution next, then Dexterity.

To focus more on fire, go with the Draconic Sorcerer. Take the Fire Bolt cantrip for attacking and setting everything else on fire from level 1, the Dragon's Breath spell by level 3, and then cast gargantuan Fireballs from level 5. Stats for a Sorcerer are normally Charisma highest, then Constitution and Dexterity.