# Are there magic items that allow a character to shapeshift?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, monsters, shapeshifting

I am [trying to create a character that can temporarily change its form into that of a dragon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/208182/is-it-possible-for-me-to-play-as-a-half-dragon-and-if-so-what-would-my-stats-be), with wings, flight, breath weapon, claws and so on -- a real dragon, even if only a small one.

Are there any magic items that would allow a character to change form in that way, similar to the druid's [Wild Shape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#WildShape-167) ability?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148512/discussion-on-question-by-drake-the-dragon-are-there-shapeshifting-magic-items); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 6):

### Yes, but no reusable ones

*Fizban's Treasury of Dragons* offers the [***Potion of Dragon's Majesty***](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4047222-potion-of-dragons-majesty), a legendary potion (p. 24):

> This potion looks like liquid gold, with a single scale from a chromatic, gem, or metallic dragon suspended in it. **When you drink this potion, you transform into an adult dragon of the same kind as the dragon the scale came from. The transformation lasts for 1 hour.** Any equipment you are wearing or carrying melds into your new form or falls to the ground (your choice). For the duration, you use the game statistics of the adult dragon instead of your own, but you retain your languages, personality, and memories. You can't use a dragon's Change Shape or its legendary or lair actions.

So, this will allow you to temporarily change form to a real dragon, one time.

However, it is not only a single use consumable, it also is *legendary*, which means you are normally not supposed to get access to it [before you are 11th level](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/awarding-magic-items) (*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 135) – and according to the *DMG* (p. 38), you would not typically have such an item as [starting equipment on any level](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/creating-a-campaign#StartingatHigherLevel), not even in a High Magic Campaign.

For your idea to play from level 1 as a part-time dragon/part-time human, the game does not offer any magic items. In fact, the guidance in the DMG p. 38 is that no matter what kind of campaign, you would not have *any* magic items on level 1 anyways, so magic items would not be a solution there, even if such an item existed. And, since magic items are always dependent on what the DM gives you, this is also not something you can decide by yourself when creating a character by the rules before having met your DM.

The options already discussed in [your original question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/208182/75095) are your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

### The spells **True Polymorph** and **Shapechange** can do this so you have options:

1. Get spell scrolls to cast true polymorph or Shapechange on yourself (purchased or manufactured). It's a 9th level spell, so the scrolls would typically be hard to get, but if your DM is okay with it then it's okay.
2. A glyph of warding with the true polymorph or Shapechange spell on it would also work, but these can't be carried around except for genie warlock vessel and other shenanigans are used.

Now these are both 9th level spells and I'm guessing you probably don't have access to them. So you'd need a cooperative DM to allow these, or just ask to homebrew a way.

Comment: Glyph of Warding for 9th level spells is hard to pull off, as PCs only have 1 9th level slot outside of epic boons, so you cannot cast both a 9th level spell and the 9th level glyph needed to put it in at the same time.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin Spell scrolls. :) If your DM lets you scribe them, problem solved with money.

Comment: @guildsbounty Yes, that should work!

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin There are some ways to get around that if you have an epic boon or a DM who will allow you to start casting it at the end of a long rest and use your spell slots for both days. Tricky but possible.

Comment: The scroll approach is extremely impractical. Don't forget that to use a 9th level spell scroll you need to have the spell on your class' spells list and _pass a DC 19 check_ with your spellcasting ability until you have slots to just cast it naturally or the scroll is wasted. That's is far from reliable even with a 20 in the ability. Scribing a 9th level scroll takes _48 weeks_ and costs _250,000 gp_ and you'd need to be able to prepare the spell already to begin with. Buying one someone else made would likely be even more expensive for them to be able to profit off of it.